# Want to use array contents' values in a php library code instead of an object

Tags: php

I am very new to php and don't know how to describe my problem, but the thing is...

call the database

```
$Library->setApiToken("default");

$horsedb = $Library->getDataBase("horsedb");
```

Then choose which DB fields I wanna call

```
$theDBfields = array("Ofields" =>
array (
"aaaa",
"bbbb",
"cccc"
),

"Hfields" =>
array (
"wwww", 
"eeee", 
"rrrr", 

)
);



//vv #1 This works
$horsedb->libraryCode($theDBfields[Hfields][0], $theDBfields[Hfields][1], $theDBfields[Hfields][2]);

//vv #2 This works, too
$horsedb->libraryCode("wwww", "eeee", "rrrr");


//vv #3 but this doesn't, it returns syntax error. But i wanna do something like this
$horsedb->libraryCode($theDBfields[Hfields]);
```

I expected that `libraryCode($theDBfields[Hfields]);` would do the same thing as `libraryCode("wwww", "eeee", "rrrr");` or `libraryCode($theDBfields[Hfields][0], $theDBfields[Hfields][1], $theDBfields[Hfields][2]);`, but apparently it doesn't.

---

there are actually so much stuff inside the array, so i wanna just use array instead of writing something like Hfields][0], Hfields][1], ... forever.

this seems like a very simple and easy problem, but I couldn't find any good solution.

Please help...

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve?

Comment: What does `$horsedb->libraryCode` do ... how does it receive/handle the input? ... you should add that piece of code to your question, because your problem should be fixed there :)

Comment: I am trying to get DB field data and the libraryCode is to select DB fields that I wanna call.  when I use $theDBfields[Hfields] in libraryCode(), just the whole page crashes and return error code

Comment: Since PHP 5.6 it's possible for the library to use the variadic argument http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Answer (score 0):

This is something close to what you got:

```
$horsedb->libraryCode($theDBfields[Hfields][0], $theDBfields[Hfields][1], $theDBfields[Hfields][2]);
/* ^ your current call*/

/** Other stuff **/

public function libraryCode($A,$B,$C){/* CURRENT */
    /* Your receiving function */
    /* ... function stuff */
}
```

This could be transformed to this:

```
$horsedb->libraryCode($theDBfields[Hfields]);
/* ^ your wanted call*/

/** Other stuff **/

public function libraryCode($Incomming){/* CHANGED */
    $A = $Incomming[0];/* NEW */
    $B = $Incomming[1];/* NEW */
    $C = $Incomming[2];/* NEW */
    /* Your receiving function */
    /* ... function stuff */
}
```

... The second example’s `$A`, `$B` and `$C`, must be the same names as in the current example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still gives me syntax error. I think as soon as I put '$theDBfields[Hfields]' inside the libraryCode, it crashes everything...

Comment: Did you change the 'libraryCode' function as suggested?

Comment: You need to show me the receiving function ... the `libraryCode`-function ... You should edit that into your question...

Comment: the function is not something I can edit. it is in the DB service provider's library... So I think there is no easy workaround... Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yeah, but I learnt and surprised to know that  converting something like `($array)` into `($array[0], $array[1], ...)` isn't easy

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `call_user_func_array` to turn array to list of arguments

```
call_user_func_array([$horsedb, 'libraryCode'], $theDBfields[Hfields]);
```

[Here you can see how it works](https://eval.in/400970)

Comment: Since PHP 5.6 variadic parameters are allowed (if library implement the feature) http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: What is `it didn't work` ? maybe for your version of php you should change syntax to `call_user_func_array(array($horsedb, 'libraryCode'), $theDBfields[Hfields]);` ?